# Realm - Insert if realm object does not exist else update

Tags: react-native, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using Realm in my react native project. Realm is encrypted. I am storing user object in it and there will be only one user so I have set the Id to be 1 always.

when the object exists, I just want to update it instead of create. How can i do it. as of now I can create it but once created I am unable to update it.

It errors with a message

`Error: Attempting to create an object of type 'User' with an existing primary key value '1'.`

my code:

```
    //user schema functions
export const insertUser = user => new Promise ((resolve, reject) => {    
    var encryptedPin = cryptoEncryptTest(getGlobalPin());
    Realm.open(
    {path: 'retailApp.realm',
        schema: [ userSchema],
        schemaVersion: 0, //optional
        encryptionKey: encryptedPin }
    //databaseOptions
    ).then(realm => {
        realm.write(() => {
            realm.create(USER_SCHEMA, user);
            resolve(user);
        });
    }).catch((error) => reject(error));
});
```

I read about `copyToRealm` and `append` but I am not sure how to use and which is the write way. I tried to delete it before inserting but I dont think that is the right way of doing it.

please suggest how to achieve this.

Thanks
R

Answer (score 0):

You can update

```
 var song = realm.objects('song')//replace with your object(USER_SCHEMA)
            realm.write(() => {
                realm.delete(song);
                realm.create('song', currentSong, true);
            })
```